# Microk8s Traefik Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I have set up a microk8s one node cluster as a test and installed and configured metalLB as a load-balancer alongside Traefik. It is working because when I set up an ingress router to whoami, it works perfectly fine. However, when setting up an ingress route to the Traefik dashboard, the page loads but the elements on it struggle to load the dashboard and I am unsure why. Could I get some help please?

Here is my yaml:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: dashboard
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`traefik-test.here`) && PathPrefix(`/dashboard`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: api@internal
          kind: TraefikService
```

Yet my dashboard looks like this: [image: Traefik Dashboard]

Comment: Fixed by adding /api to the match line: - match: Host(`traefik-test.here`) && ( PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding PathPrefix "api".

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: dashboard
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`traefik-test.here`) && ( PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`) )
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: api@internal
          kind: TraefikService
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).